# Creating groups of variables within the same observation in stata

Tags: stata

I'd like some help with a large dataset I'm currently analysing in Stata. The dataset has multiple test results (result) and the time between each test result in hours (tt) within the same observation in the following form:

```
result1 result2 result3 result4 result5 result6 result7 result8 result9 result10
   |______| |______| |______||______||______||______||______||______||______|
     tt1       tt2      tt3     tt4     tt5     tt6     tt7     tt8     tt9
```

I would like to group the results according to time such that if there was a delay more than 24 hours since the previous result, it would be analysed as a new "group" (i.e if tt1-3 are <24 hours and tt4>24 hours, then result1-3 would be one group and result4-6 would be another provided tt5-6 are <24 hours also). I then need to use these groups to determine rate and percentage change for each. Please note, not all observations have all results available, some may only have 1-2. Some direction for the stata code for this would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: How do you want the grouping to happen if there are missing values? The one thing I can say is that this is probably best analyzed in long format, which would require `reshape long`.

Comment: Also, providing a minimal example of your data would increase your chances of getting a useful answer.